# perf cannot find external module symbols

Tags: symbols, kernel-module, perf

When running `perf` it finds the kernel symbols and symbols of my program but it does not find external module symbols. I have written a kernel module which I load using `insmod` how can I tell `perf` to find its symbols as well?

I am running a 2.6.37.6 kernel (can't upgrade), my `perf` does not yet support the dwarf option but I think its a symbol issue. I have compiled everything with `-g -fno-omit-frame-pointer`

Comment: You can get perf from newer kernel (already compiled or compile yourself) and use it on older kernel. Sometimes this will work and provide you additional capabilities like dwarf option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to make it a kernel module, then perf could find its symbols:

```
IN_TREE_DIR=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/modulename
mkdir -p $IN_TREE_DIR
cp modulename.ko $IN_TREE_DIR
depmod -a
```

Comment: The standard place for external modules is: /lib/modules/`uname -r`/extra